# Black (blank) screen when using Navigator.pop() after using a custom page animation with PageRouteBuilder(). How do I fix this?

Tags: flutter

I'm getting a black screen after I changed to a custom page animation with PageRouteBuilder(). Without using the custom animation, it works perfectly. But when I added the custom animation, the `Navigator.push()` still worked, but when the screen is popped, it returns a black screen.

Here is the code:

```dart
// This is the button to change the route.
// I'm using the condition statements to change the behaviour 
// depending on the route from which it is clicked.
NavigationBarButton(
  icon: Icons.people,
  title: 'My Network',
  isActive: widget.activeScreen == MyNetworkScreen.screen_id ? true : false,
  onPressed: () {
    if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name == HomeScreen.screen_id) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(_noAnimationBuilder(
        page: MyNetworkScreen(),
        pageName: MyNetworkScreen.screen_id,
      ));
    } else if (ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name == MyNetworkScreen.screen_id) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(_noAnimationBuilder(
        page: MyNetworkScreen(),
        pageName: MyNetworkScreen.screen_id));
    }
  },
),


// This is the animation.
Route _noAnimationBuilder({required Widget page, required String pageName}) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return child;
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to figure it out. The problem was because I was using named routes in my navigation but when I use the custom animation to create a new route, I didn't set the name of the new route.

I just had to change my code to look like:

```dart
Route _noAnimationBuilder({required Widget page, required String pageName}) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return child;
    },
    settings: RouteSettings(name: pageName), // This is what I had to add.
  );
}
```

For the named routes, this is what my `MaterialApp()` file looks like:

```dart
class LinkedInClone extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'LinkedIn Clone',
      initialRoute: LoadingScreen.screen_id,
      routes: {
        // In each screen, I defined a static const String `screen_id` and used it to name the routes so if I don't misspell it.
        LoadingScreen.screen_id: (context) => LoadingScreen(),
        HomeScreen.screen_id: (context) => HomeScreen(),
        MessagingScreen.screen_id: (context) => MessagingScreen(),
        MyNetworkScreen.screen_id: (context) => MyNetworkScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```